# GIT stashed date

Tags: git

Given the following stash content:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On fixes: animations-fixes
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 62aecaa Merge pull request #10 from SOURCE/branch-name
```

is there any way to have the same list, but including the date on which the stash was created?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A stash entry is just a regular git commit internally. So you can read its date ("commit date" or "author date") to know when it was created.

As mentioned in the manpage of `git stash`, you can use the formatting options for `git log` when invoking `git stash list`. So to get the date, you could use `git log`'s option `--format`:

```
git stash list --format="%gd: %ci - %gs"
```

This produces output like:

```
stash@{0}: 2014-04-23 11:36:39 +0500 - WIP on master: d072412 Do some stuff
```

That format uses `%ci`, which prints the committer date in ISO 8601 format. Use `%cr` for relative dates:

```
stash@{0}: 8 minutes ago - WIP on master: d072412 Do some stuff
```

See [the manpage of `git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) (section "PRETTY FORMATS") for more formatting options.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, `log` formatting applies. If you are looking for the default log format:

`git stash list --pretty=medium`

To see author and committer dates:

`git stash list --pretty=fuller`

And to inspect only one stash at a time (`stash@{2}` in the example):

`$ git log -1 --pretty=fuller stash@{2}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the date, without time, use

```
git stash list --format="%gd: %cd - %gs" --date=short stash@{0}
```

produces:

```
stash@{0}: 2017-09-22 - WIP on master: d072412 Do some stuff
```

`%cd` means date formatted according to the `--date=` parameter. `stash@{0}` is necessary, or the stash id will be turned into a date too.