# How to view stash date/timestamp next to stash id?

Tags: git, git-stash

Using `git stash list` shows me the list of stashes with their IDs. Using `git stash list --date=local` or `git stash list --date=relative` gives me their times, but I have no idea what their corresponding ID is.

I want to acquire a stash at a certain time.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263781/git-stashed-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT stashed date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263781/git-stashed-date)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`git stash list` simply runs `git log` with a particular set of options:

```
list_stash () {
        have_stash || return 0
        git log --format="%gd: %gs" -g --first-parent -m "$@" $ref_stash --
}
```

The `$@` part inserts whatever additional options you've specified (none by default, but `--date=relative` in this case).<sup>1</sup>

When you use `--date=relative` this modifies the output from `%gd`: instead of a short reflog with an *index*, you get a short reflog with a *relative time stamp*:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: ...
$ git stash list --date=relative
stash@{4 minutes ago}: ...
```

The solution in this case is to use your own explicit format, rather than just letting `--date=relative` modify how `%gd` gets displayed.  For instance:

```
$ git stash list --format='%gd (%cr): %gs'
stash@{0} (4 minutes ago): ...
```

(`%cr` inserts the commit's committer time stamp, in relative format—this makes sense once you know that all `git stash` does is make a couple of commits for you, with the commits being stored on the special `stash` ref instead of on a branch).

---

<sup>1</sup>On reviewing this answer, I note that the `--first-parent` and `-m` arguments (literally present in the `git stash` code) seem redundant at first, because of the `-g` argument.  The `-g` argument to `git log` tells it to look only at the reflog, rather than the commit history, in which case, `--first-parent` means nothing.  Meanwhile `-m` tells `git diff` to split a merge commit, but we're looking at commit logs, not diffs, so what is this doing here?

The answer is that `git log` *can* show a patch, for which it runs `git diff`, so if you give `-p` as an argument, the `--first-parent -m` limits this diff to comparing the commit to which the stash reflog points against its first parent.  The [stash bag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452) commit to which the reflog entry points is the work-tree commit, whose *first* parent is the original commit on which the stash-bag hangs.  (Its second parent is the index commit and its third parent, if present, is the all or untracked files commit.)  So these options are there to make `git stash list -p` diff the stash's work-tree commit against the commit that was current when the stash itself was made.

This is clever, but quite obscure! :-)

Answer (score 31):

You can actually use the `stash@<date>` syntax directly when referring to a stash:

```
$ git stash list --date=local
stash@{Sun Dec 21 22:32:14 2014}: WIP on develop: 7142a6e Update data files
stash@{Fri Dec 12 10:02:20 2014}: WIP on develop: c72abda Add initial calibration data
stash@{Wed Dec 10 10:02:05 2014}: WIP on master: 1d27422 Bug fix for gadgeteer
$ git show 'stash@{Fri Dec 12 10:02:20 2014}'
commit a096484501caf14942f01a6500a5d0c3476d3145
Merge: c72abda 861fff6
Author: Robert Xiao <brx@cs.cmu.edu>
Date:   Fri Dec 12 13:02:20 2014 -0500

    WIP on develop: c72abda Add initial calibration data
...
$ git stash pop 'stash@{Fri Dec 12 10:02:20 2014}'
```

No need to get the ID of the stash at all! This even works with `date=relative` as long as the relative dates are unique.